# convert or parse string to JSON object

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, json

There was an interview question(Javascript) which my friend and me unable to solve it for a long time, so thought of asking here,

```
Question:
String:
2014<18.3,11.4,12.1,19.5,1000&&11.2,34.5,67.1,18,20000>name=sample,position=engineer,company=abc
```

and the end reult should be a JSON Objwct with following format. Can anyone please help to solve this issue.

```
Output:
{[
    {"Proposal":"2014"}, 
    {"values":"[18.3,11.4,12.1,19.5],[11.2,34.5,67.1,18]"},
    {"Items":"[1000,20000]"},
    {"name":"sample"},
    {"position":"engineer"},
    {"company":"abc"},
]}
```

Expecting a solution and explanation please.

Thanks,
Basky

Comment: @downvote : Can you please let me know why you have downvote to the question ?

Comment: where are your attempts? This looks a lot more like a homework assignment that you expect people to write the code for

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is your solution.

1. Input string should have all the parameter, if any of the parameter is missing below code will break.
2. Logic is dynamic to support any number of numeric values where as last digit will consider as Items.
3. Logic also support the n number of key/value pair in the input string.

Check below code in console.

```
var JsonOutput = [];
var sRawInput = "2014<18.3,11.4,12.1,19.5,1000&&11.2,34.5,67.1,18,20000>name=sample,position=engineer,company=abc";

JsonOutput.push({ "Proposal" : sRawInput.split("<")[0] });

var oValues = sRawInput.split("<")[1].split(">")[0].split("&&");
var oActualValues = [];
var oActualItems = [];

$(oValues).each(function(Ind, Val){
    oActualValues.push(Val.split(",").slice(0, Val.split(",").length - 1).join());
    oActualItems.push(Val.split(",")[Val.split(",").length - 1]);
});

JsonOutput.push({ "Values" : oActualValues });
JsonOutput.push({ "Items" : oActualItems });

var OtherValues = sRawInput.split(">")[1].split(",");

$(OtherValues).each(function(Ind, Val){
    JsonOutput.push(JSON.parse("{\"" + Val.split("=")[0] + "\":\"" + Val.split("=")[1] + "\"}"));
});

console.log(JsonOutput);
console.log(JSON.stringify(JsonOutput));
```

Answer (score 0):

Note:
Values is incorrect as it should contain 2 arrays and not a single array.

Items is incorrect as it should contain numbers and not a string.

Also the outside wrapper should be an obj {}

Comment: This should be a comment

Comment: Could you improve your answer a little more?